# Schedule a sequence of DML statements in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a BQ table and need to schedule a series of DML statements on it (inserts & merge). I am trying to replicate the Oracle PL/SQL functionality where you can group DML statements into a single procedure that can be scheduled.

So, the goal is (i) group a series of DML statements into a script, and (ii) schedule the script for execution. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi Denim, The tern PL/SQL is not a BigQuery term as far as I know. Anyway, in BigQuery you have a Merge command, Are you using it? Some examples can be found in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples). If this is not helpful can you provide SQL examples to clarify better what's not working

Comment: Thanks Tamir. I was referring to Oracle PL/SQL functionality. The question is how can I group DML statements that need to run sequentially into a single simple script and execute it.

Comment: Great, So back to my question have you checked BigQuery [merge](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples) command which handles insert/update/delete in one command on a single table? If yes please provide an example what you tried and what is not working

Comment: I know merge and I've been using it extensively. Again, I need to sequentially run multiple DML statements including more than one merge.

Comment: The only way to do this is to use an API which will wrap your SQL code although I have a feeling this is not what you want to do. You will need to submit a change request to Bigquery team if this is indeed the case

Comment: I can also use the bq command-line tool to submit the DML statements one by one. I was just wondering if there is a better way. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Please keep an eye on future release notes. BigQuery scripting and store procedure support are features to come.

Comment: You can do this easily with [Magnus](https://potensio.zendesk.com/hc/en-us). [Try It now](https://potens.io/). Add as many BigQuery Tasks as needed and schedule resulted workflow using pre-defined schedules or fine-tune using quartz cron syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting is supported in scheduled query now. However, scripting query, when being scheduled, doesn't support setting a destination table for now. You still need to use DDL/DML to make change to existing table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE destinationTable AS
SELECT *
FROM sourceTable
WHERE date >= maxDate
```